# How to move folder in a path to another path in windows using python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a script to move all contents from source folder and create/replace into destination folder without removing any existing files/folders in destination. The contents of test1 folder will be a html file along with some images in png format.

**source path**: C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\LocalFolder\reports\v2
**source folder Name**: *test1*

**Destination path**: T:\remoteReports\myTests
**Path to be created while copying:** \LocalFolder\reports\v2
**Folder to copy from source into destination**: *test1*

**final path in destinaton:** T:\remoteReports\myTests\LocalFolder\reports\v2\test1

I have taken a piece of code from stack overflow and using it for my application but running the script is not creating the path and folder in the destination.

```
import time
import os
import random
import shutil
import pathlib
def move_files(root_src_dir,root_dst_dir):
print(root_src_dir)
print(root_dst_dir)
for src_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_src_dir):
    dst_dir = src_dir.replace(root_src_dir,root_dst_dir, 1)
    if not os.path.exists(dst_dir):
        os.makedirs(dst_dir)
    for file_ in files:
        src_file = os.path.join(src_dir, file_)
        dst_file = os.path.join(dst_dir, file_)
        if os.path.exists(dst_file):
        # in case of the src and dst are the same file
            if os.path.samefile(src_file, dst_file):
                continue
    os.remove(dst_file)
    shutil.move(src_file, dst_dir) 
 srcPath = os.path.join("C:", "Users", os.getlogin(),"Documents", "LocalFolder", "v2", "test1")
 dstPath = os.path.join("T:", "remoteReports", "myTests", "LocalFolder", "v2", "test1")
 move_files(srcPath,dstPath )
```

It will be helpful if someone can guide me with this !

Comment: I see you are using the `shutil` standard library module. Did you try reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to copy all files from one folder to another:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copy

src = Path(r"C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\LocalFolder\reports\v2")
dst = Path(r"T:\remoteReports\myTests\LocalFolder\reports\v2")
for file in src.iterdir():
    if file.is_file() and not (dst / file.name).is_file():
        copy(file, dst)
```

If you want to copy whole tree including sub directories and it's content, you can apply [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

```py
from pathlib import Path
from os import walk
from shutil import copy

src = Path(r"C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\LocalFolder\reports\v2")
dst = Path(r"T:\remoteReports\myTests\LocalFolder\reports\v2")
for dir_name, _, filenames in walk(src):
    src_path = Path(dir_name)
    dst_path = dst / src_path.relative_to(src)
    if not dst_path.is_dir():
        dst_path.mkdir()
    for file in filenames:
        dst_file = dst_path / file
        if not dst_file.is_file():
            copy(src_path / file, dst_path)
```

Or you can make function from code I've suggested firstly and use it recursively:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copy

def copy_folder(src_path, dst_path):
    if not dst_path.is_dir():
        dst_path.mkdir()
    for file in src_path.iterdir():
        if file.is_dir():
            copy_folder(file, dst_path / file.relative_to(src_path))  # recursion
        elif file.is_file() and not (dst_path / file.name).is_file():
            copy(file, dst_path)

src = Path(r"C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\LocalFolder\reports\v2")
dst = Path(r"T:\remoteReports\myTests\LocalFolder\reports\v2")
copy_folder(src, dst)
```

---

**BUT** You don't really need to implement all this manually, because [`shutil.copytree()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) already exists and does exactly the same that all options I've provided before. *Important notice: you should pass `dirs_exist_ok` argument to not throw an exception if directory in destination path already exists.*

```py
from shutil import copy, copytree
from os.path import exists

src = r"C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\LocalFolder\reports\v2"
dst = r"T:\remoteReports\myTests\LocalFolder\reports\v2"
copytree(src, dst, copy_function=lambda s, d: not exists(d) and copy(s, d), dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

Here I've used `lambda` which check does file already exist to not overwrite it, you can omit this parameter if you don't care that files will be overwritten.

---

If you want to move all files, you can pass [`shutil.move()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) to `copy_function`:

```py
from shutil import move, copytree
...
copytree(src, dst, copy_function=move, dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

It'll move all files, but leave tree directory. If you want to copy all directory tree and delete it from source, you can call [`shutil.copytree()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) and [`shutil.rmtree()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree):

```py
from shutil import copytree, rmtree
...
copytree(src, dst, dirs_exist_ok=True)
rmtree(src)
```

Comment: Though I have specified the path here, it will be dynamic. Meaning I will have to capture the path from different variables in runtime. Hence, I am using os.join() to put them together.

Comment: Will this method remain the same even if I am not using the raw path for src & dst ?

Comment: @Krishna, I'm using here not raw path, but [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) objects, so you can pass any `Path` object and it will work.

Comment: @Krishna, check updated answer, I've added important part at the end

Comment: I have just tried this code. It does copy the files into the folder I specify but I wanted to copy the folder into the destination by creating the directories in the destination same as the source path.

Comment: @Krishna, last option should work for you perfectly.

Comment: The last option works well for copy. I have to do something like this to MOVE and i need overwrite, so lambda is not required. But This answer partially does what I need for now. Need to find an equivalent to move and replace now .. thanks!

Comment: @Krishna, you just need to pass `move` instead of lambda, check updated answer. You can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer if it helped you.